# view attributes from feature service and export to CSV or copy to clipboard

Tags: javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, fields-attributes

I have a Geo-Processing service that generates summary statistics of an area of interest.  What I would like to know is;

1. Simple method to display the data in my Webpage.  Is Dgrid the recommended route?
2. How would I allow a user to download the attribute's as a CSV or DBF file?  I don't mind creating another Geo-Processor to handle this request, but how would I implement the data extraction to download.
3. Related to item two above, I need to provide access to the records for my users to do futher analysis and reporting.  How would I enable a copy to clip board function of the records?

I am working in JavaScript, with Esri API and server 10.2.2 REST.